# Asyncronous requests in AngularJS performed sequentially

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I need to perform 3 requests concurently , here is the code:

```
for (var url in urls){
    console.log('queued!');
    $http.jsonp(url, {timeout: 10000}).then(function (response, status, headers, config) {
            if (response.data.status == 'success') {
                console.log(response.data);
            }
        }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    );
}
```

However, this requests perform sequentially(the second request takes about 8 seconds, but the third about 1 and the third ends after the second)

**UPD:**
I dont need requests to end at the same time, I need them to run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont need requests to end at the same time, I need them to run in parallel.

This is actually what `$q.all` does

### $q.all([async1(), async2() .....])

> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when **all** of the input promises are resolved.

For example:

```
 $q.all([
            serviceAPI.getCall_1(_date),
            serviceAPI.getCall_2(_date),
            serviceAPI.getCall_3(_date),            
            serviceAPI.getCall_4(_date),
            serviceAPI.getCall_5(_date)
            ])
            .then(function(result)
            {    
              /* here all above mentioned async calls finished */
 
              $scope.response_1 = result[0];
              $scope.response_2 = result[1];
              $scope.response_3 = result[2];
              $scope.response_4 = result[3];
              $scope.response_5 = result[4];
           });
```

First off, create list of promises (*you can use loop `for`*) andafter write only one *resolve* where its easily to fetch all results by providing proper index (1,2,3,4,5 ...).

Comment: First solution is not concurrent at all, It waits for the previous request to lauch the next. Its asynchronous but nor concurrent.

Comment: I think the second solution is similar to mine, except collecting request results. I dont need it, all necessary logic implemented in "then" callback.

Comment: @СергейДубинин I left with 2nd one. If you put breaking point in `then{}` , you enter there when all calls finished. So I think its what you want